# Is it possible add different types of objects to a favorites list in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

I have a list of trucks in a mock database with various attributes as well as a list of block parties also in a mock database with various attributes (they are different from the truck attributes). Each of the lists populate two different UITableViews in two different xibs in a tab bar application. I have a third tab bar xib for favorites. I want the ability of users to tap an "Add this to Favorites" button so that either a truck or a block party can be placed into the list of favorites. Does anyone have an idea of how this might be possible? If not, both then at least how would I be able to add the Trucks to the favorites?

```
   // Initialize the mock database of trucks.
listContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               [Truck truckWithCuisine:@"American Cuisine" name:@"Buttermilk Truck" menu:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Steve/Desktop/Truck Tracker App/Truck Tracker App/Buttermilk Truck Menu.tiff"] latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.1] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.1]schedule:@"7/15/12"],
               [Truck truckWithCuisine:@"American Cuisine" name:@"In N Out Burgers" menu:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Steve/Desktop/Truck Tracker App/Truck Tracker App/Lobsta Truck Menu.tiff"]
                              latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 23.2] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 80.2] schedule: nil],
               [Truck truckWithCuisine:@"Mexican Cuisine" name:@"Hacienda Mexican" menu: nil
                              latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 42.3] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 64.3] schedule: nil],
               [Truck truckWithCuisine:@"Indian Cuisine" name:@"Naboo Indian"  menu: nil
                              latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.4] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0.4] schedule: nil],
               [Truck truckWithCuisine:@"Italian Cuisine" name:@"Vito's Italian" menu: nil
                              latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 33.9698156] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: -118.4185009] schedule: nil],
               nil];
selectedTruck = nil;
NSLog(@"delegate: %d", [listContent count]);    

//Initialize the mock database of users.
listPeople = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              [Person personWithEmail:@"stephen@techgroupintl.com" password:@"test" type:@"User"],
              [Person personWithEmail:@"dondi@lmu.edu" password:@"test" type:@"Truck Owner"],
              nil];
selectedPerson = nil;

//Initialize the mock database of block parties.
listParty = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [BlockParty blockpartyWithName:@"Westside Food Truck Central" listOfTrucks: nil latitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:200.1] longitude: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 146.5] schedule:@"7/15/12" ],
             [BlockParty blockpartyWithName:@"Venice Food Truck Paradise" listOfTrucks:nil latitude:nil longitude:nil schedule:nil], 
            nil];
selectedBlockParty = nil;
```

Comment: Are the truck and block parties both going to use the same type of cell to display their information in the table view?  Are they going to push a new controller with more details if they are selected?

Comment: They will both use the same type of cell, and they do push to a new view controller if they are tapped.

Comment: How are the truck and the block parties stored?

Comment: Here is how I presently have them:

Comment: added the code I have so far above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I can think of is by posting a notification along with the object from trucks tableview (class) and from the parties tableview (class) when a row is selected.  Then in your Favorites class, implement an observer of that notification message and add the object  to your tableview when a message is received.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a BOOL favorite attribute to each of your classes and set it to YES when you select "Add this to Favorites". Then in your Favorites tab, you fetch all objects that have the favorite attribute set to YES.